# Implementando IRepository en IUnitOfWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Hola ¿como puede mi interface UoF heredar de IRepository? teniendo esto:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IDisposable
```

IoW

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IRepository
{
    int Save();
}
```

Comment: pero las interfaces no se heredan se implementan, edita el codigo porque no se visualiza correctamente

Comment: Leandro ya lo edite

Comment: pero alli lo que defines es una "herencia" de interfaces, lo que noto es que no defines el generic  public interface IUnitOfWork : IRepository<entidad>

Comment: Si le pongo T me dice el nombre de tipo no se encontro, tambien si hago esto public interface IUnitOfWork : IRepository<T> where T : class  no se permiten declaraciones no genericas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias definir la `T` de generic tambien en la clase `UoW`

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class 
{
}

public interface IUnitOfWork<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   int Save(T entity);
}
```

Igualmente recomendaria analices ejemplos como ser

[Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application (9 of 10)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

en el titulo **Creating the Unit of Work Class**
podrias onservar que la clase de UoW no hereda de ningun repositorio

Comment: Me dice el tipo T no puede usar un parametro de tipo T en el tipo o metodo genereico IRepository<T> no hay ninguna convercion de referencia implicita de T a system Idispossable, la otra solución sería que me IRepository solo la implemente sin class que solo me sirva para Entity Framework

Comment: pero este problema se presenta cuando compilas o cual esta ejecutando ? no veo en la explicacion donde has puesto el IDisposable

Comment: Mi IRepository herada de IDisposable fijate arriba, ese problema sucede cuando edito en el codigo.

Comment: intenta usando     public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class

Comment: Bien Leandro, gracias esa es la solución

Comment: Leandro aprovechando este hilo cual es la diferencia entre public interface IRepository : IDisposable y public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class

Comment: en uno defines generic (cuando usas <T>) y en el otro no

Comment: para ayudar a tener las ideas claras: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853414/generic-repository-irepositoryt-or-irepository

Comment: Gracias me quedo claro.